# Is there any reason to continue using IntentService for handling GCM messages?

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

As you know, recently Google changed their GCM documentation, and they claim that an `IntentService` is no longer required for handling arriving GCM messages. All the handling can be done in the `BroadcastReceiver`.

When trying to figure out if there is any good reason to continue using the `IntentService`, I came across this [quote](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html):

> A Service (typically an IntentService) to which the WakefulBroadcastReceiver passes off the work of handling the GCM message, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep in the process. **Including an IntentService is optional**—you could choose to process your messages in a regular BroadcastReceiver instead, **but realistically, most apps will use a IntentService**.

Why would most apps use an `IntentService`? Are there any scenarios in which handling the GCM message directly in the `BroadcastReceiver` won't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why would most apps use an IntentService?

Because most likely whatever you are doing in response to the message will take more than 1-2ms, which means that you want to get that work off the main application thread. A common pattern for doing that in response to a broadcast is to delegate the work to an `IntentService`.

So, if your work in response to the GCM message involves:

- disk I/O
- further network I/O (e.g., retrieving additional data from your Web service)
- substantial calculations (e.g., image processing)

you will likely want to use an `IntentService` to perform that work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, if I understand correctly, if the response to the GCM message involves only displaying a notification then there is no reason to use the IntentService. Am I correct?

Comment: @Eran: That is probably safe, assuming that you are not doing disk I/O as part of showing the `Notification` (e.g., reading in some database info for populating the `Notification` contents).

Comment: @CommonsWare commiting to sharedpreferences considered as I/O?

Comment: @OfekRon: Yes, though note that `apply()` forks its own background thread for the I/O. `commit()` is synchronous and ideally is not done on the main application thread. Similarly, trying to get a `SharedPreferences` object (e.g., `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`) may do disk I/O if your request is the first time anything requested it in this process and the preferences must be read from disk.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hello, my app can push local notification via Pending Intent (not GCM notifcations) when app stay in foreground, but can not push notification when app run in background (`onPause`), android system limit it? Do I need `Intent Service` to push local notifications?